# padding-right or margin-right for content that exceeds page width (body/viewport)

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 3em;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        #content {
            width: 200em;
            height: 4em;
            background-color: #dcdcdc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The content width expands beyond the width of the page/viewport after getting data. I want to show some margin/padding at the right side of the page.

I have tried quite a few things - floats, positioning, BFC etc.

How can I get some white space to the right of the `#content` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the body is only as wide as the window, so you're not really scrolling the body, rather the canvas. (You could see this by giving the body a border; this would show that it does not grow wider than the window.)

One solution is to turn the body into an inline-block, so that it stretches with its contents, and then the padding works.

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3em;
  height: calc(100% - 6em);
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
  width: 200em;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Nothing, nothing else seems to work. After hours, I put in a hack by introducing a table, with an extra, hidden <td>, with hidden borders  ... makes me cringe. This works elegantly. Thanks.